# Unzip response stream from zipped with GZipStream (C#) in GZIPInputStream

Tags: java, gzip

I am trying to unzip a response from a .net middleware. The response has been ziped using GZipStream.

```
GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true);
```

when I used GZIPInputStream in java to unzip the file. I am getting an IOException with message "not in zip format" in the following code.

```
GZIPInputStream gzin = new GZIPInputStream(response);
```

I tried this too.

```
    ByteArrayInputStream memstream = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer2);   
  GZIPInputStream gzin = new GZIPInputStream(memstream);
```

Any help or suggestions are welcomed.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out the solution, In the response returned by the server first few bytes were not zipped so if any one is facing the same issue you just need to check the bytes. After I removed those bytes from response. It started working.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
 GZIPInputStream gis = null;
 FileOutputStream fos = null;
 try {
     gis = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("pathOfTheGZipFile"));
     fos = new FileOutputStream("pathOfDecompressedFile");
     byte[] buffer = new byte[gis.available()];
     int len;
     while((len = gis.read(buffer)) != -1){
         fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
     }
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 finally {
     fos.close();
     gis.close();  
 }
```

Comment: I am trying to unzip a server response which has been ziped

Comment: The response header does not the info. but it is zipped file I am sure of it

Comment: Are you trying to read some url and getting the data in gzip?

Comment: read the response in `InputStream` and provide the inputstreamObj to  `GZIPInputStream`

Comment: I did the same but again and again I am getting "not in zip format" from GZIPInputStream , while the c# equivalent GZipStream is able to decompress the response.